# FMDB library not found while using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, salesforce, cocoapods

I have an app in which I am using cocoapods to download third party libraries. I have Salesforce sdk and also firebase. Both Salesforce's SmartStore and Firebase are dependent on FMDB. If I remove Firebase pod and do a pod update it is compiling fine without any error. But, if I add firebase libraries to Pod, I get

> Library not found for -lFMDB
>
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to invocation)

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'App' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

# Pods for App
source 'https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS-Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

 pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
 pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
 pod 'SalesforceSDKCore','7.3.0'
 pod 'SmartStore','7.3.0'
 pod 'SmartSync','7.3.0'
 pod 'SalesforceAnalytics','7.3.0'
 pod 'SalesforceSDKCommon','7.3.0'

end
```

I am not sure what is the problem and how to resolve it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Firebase is not dependent upon FMDB.  Sharing the Podfile may help others to diagnose.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien But I have this error only when I update pod with firebase library. Otherwise it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone else has the same problem, remove libraries from Other Linker Flags. As in pod file, I have `use_frameworks!` in pod file,I believe you don't have to mention them in Other Linker Flags.